# How to get the attributes of a HTML element using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am wondering whether there is a way in which I can get the value within a given HTML element using JQuery?

Example

```
<span id="45463_test"></span>
```

<del>(using the proper tags made the code to processed)</del>

What I want is the `'45463_test'` value within the `id` attribute (using JQuery).

Thanx for the responses and the edit.

I would it such that I can get the attribute value of a tag which has been clicked.

Comment: I see in one of your comments that you only want the ID the tag that was clicked. Are you trying to get the ID from within a jQuery click handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to get the ID of the `<span/>` you clicked then it's better to apply a click event handler to each span and catch the attribute value.

```
$("span").click(function() {
  return $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You kind of need a different selector in order to tell jQuery which span element to look at.

```
$("span").attr("id")
```

Which would get the Id attr value of all spans on the page.

For example, if you had

```
<span id="mySpan" class="mySpanClass"></span>
```

you could get the IDs of all the spans with class "mySpanClass" using:

```
$("span[class='mySpanClass']").attr("id")
```

Documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Thanx for the answer, 

now is there a way to sort through the data returned, since there are many [span] tags and I would only want the id of the tag which has been clicked?

Comment: `$("span[class='mySpanClass']").attr("id")` is not needed, Use:  `$("span.mySpanClass").attr("id")`

Answer (score 1):

Get: `$("#45463_test").attr('id');`
Set: `$("#45463_test").attr('id','new value');`

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

can't help but noticed,

you need something like this..

```
$("span").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

## [good to play demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GXgMm/)