# How to read a div property in js?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the attributes of a HTML element using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211326/how-to-get-the-attributes-of-a-html-element-using-jquery)

I have a piece of JS and I need to read property 'value' from a div.

I do this:

```
$('#calendar_event_path')
```

I get this as and answer:

```
[<div id=​"calendar_event_path" value=​"company_events_index">​</div>​]
```

How can I get "company_events_index" value from the div?

Comment: FWIW, `value` is not a valid attribute for `div` elements.

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice that, deleted my answer. **Felix Kling** is right. Instead of `value` use a `data-` attribute.

Comment: voted to close, just did not know the proper lingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use data-value attribute in your html

```
<div id=​"calendar_event_path" data-value=​"company_events_index">​</div>
```

the in jQuery fetch its value using data()

```
var sumthng = $('#calendar_event_path').data("value");
```